# How to compare two strings for a binary search tree

Tags: c, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to compare two strings to see where it should go as a leaf node from the root and so fourth. I keep trying to use string compare and I get an error. I am very unfamiliar with binary trees in c and need help inserting nodes.

Here is the code I have so far that is giving me an error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLEN 15

typedef struct treeNode{
  char string[MAXLEN+1];
  struct treeNode *left;
  struct treNode *right;
}treeNode;

treeNode * insert(treeNode *node, char s[MAXLEN+1]){
  if(node == NULL){
    treeNode *temp;
    temp = (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    strncpy(temp -> string, s, sizeof(treeNode));
    temp -> left = NULL;
    temp -> right = NULL;
    return temp;
  }

  else-if(strcmp(node->string,char s)>0){

  }
}
```

Comment: Just use language you tagged your question with - in C# you can simply compare strings with regular `<` and `>` (like `"aaa"<"bbb"`) :)

Comment: I am required to use c for this project. Sorry i tagged c#. I wish i was able to use objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think you should change

```
strcmp(node->string,char s);
```

And replace it with

```
strcmp(node->string,s);
```

In strcmp if the result is greater than zero then the first argument is greater than the second.

So if your if else statement evaluates true then node->string is greater than s.

And if strcmp is less than zero then the second argument is greater than the first value.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems in your program right now:

1. "else-if" should be "else if"
2. strcmp(node->string,char s) should be strcmp(node->string, s)
3. No main method